# Linux Mint 17 can't connect to library wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I have some troubles with connecting to library wifi NTK-Simple. I can connect to this NTK-Simple with my mobile, also I can connect with this mint laptop to wifi at my home, my mobile hotspot etc. It is wifi without password,you just connect to wifi and then in browser you type your library name and pw. When I am trying to connect, it is stucked on Obtaining IP address.. I am using wicd and it is only one network manager I have installed. I also tryed network-manager, with same result. Drivers should be OK. Laptop is lenovo ThinkPad T410. here is my wcid log file. 
[wcid.log](http://www.filedropper.com/wicd)

Answer (score 1):

Your situation seems very similar to that reported [in this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wicd/+bug/1075159) for dhclient (mind you, dhclient, not wicd). Lacking more info is impossible to say precisely whether this is indeedthe case.

However, since this is a free wifi, it is easy enough to connect to  it. First make sure you have stopped `wicd`, and killed all instances of `dhclient` and 'wpa_ANYTHING`. If you do not, you will not be able to connect.

Then issue:

```
      iwconfig wlan0 essid NAME_OF_NETWORK
      dhclient -v wlan0
```

(you might have to omit the `-v` flag, I am not sure about Mint). Now make sure that your routing is set up correctly,

```
      # ip route show
        default via 192.168.73.1 dev wlan0 
        192.168.73.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.73.65
```

It is important that you have the line beginning with `default`, which is hte one that sets your gateway.

Also make sure that the file `/etc/resolv.conf` contains at least one line beginning with `nameserver`. If it does not,

```
     echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
     echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

You should be good to go.